# How to fix code that extracts even numbered index values in an array of a sentence and combines it with odd numbered index values?

Tags: c, arrays

Basically, my code is supposed to encrypt a sentence(or word) by taking out all the even numbered index values(starting from 0) and the odd numbered index values and placing the even index values before the odd index values.
For example, a word like "test" (0)t(1)e(2)s(3)t should be printed as (0)t(2)s(1)e(3)t or "tset". There aren't supposed to be any numbers printed, I just used them to show the odd and even index values.
My code works sometimes, depending on where it is run. I seem to be getting differing results between code blocks and an online compiler I tried. I suspect there must be a larger issue to blame for this inconsistency. Can anyone help me to see what I'm doing wrong so I can finally understand and rectify my errors?

I have tried using one counter to input both even and odd index values into one array but I was having errors with that as well so I decided to put them into separate arrays and then use `strcat` to combine them. Is there a way to make it work with the method I've shown in my code or should I go back to the previous method?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1000

int main()
{
    char message[SIZE];
    char even[SIZE];
    char odd[SIZE];
    int length,j=0;
    printf("Enter a word or sentence.\n");
    fgets(message,SIZE,stdin);

    printf("Your message is: %s\n",message);
    message[strcspn(message, "\n")] = 0;
    length=strlen(message);
    printf("The length of the message is: %d\n",length);
    for(int i=0;i<length;i+=2){

        even[i/2]=message[i];

       // printf("%c\n",even[i/2]);
    }

    for(int i=1;i<length;i+=2){
        odd[j]=message[i];
        j++;
    }
    printf("The even letters are: %s\n",even);
    printf("The odd letters are: %s\n",odd);

    strcat(even,odd);
    printf("%s",even);


/*printf("\nFInalyy.");
   for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
      for(j=i+1;j<=count;j++){
         if(strcmp(allmessages[i],allmessages[j])>0){
            strcpy(temp,allmessages[i]);
            strcpy(allmessages[i],allmessages[j]);
            strcpy(allmessages[j],temp);
         }
      }
   printf("The original messages in alphabetical order are: ");
   for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
      puts(allmessages[i]);*/
    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly when I type in words like "test" or "sentence". Sometimes I type in sentences like "this is a test sentence" and it would work perfectly then one time it would print out some random garbage letters along with the encrypted sentence. I would like to know how to fix this and to understand why it works perfectly with the same entry a few times then just stops. I used  https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler to test it the last few times so my results are based on that.

Successful Result:

[image: Successful Result]

Unsuccessful Result using the same entry:

[image: Unsuccessful Result using the same entry]

Comment: Posting text as text is more useful than posting text as a picture.  Please replace the  pictures with text.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a slightly shorter approach by simply using two indexes to build your encrypted string (like `evenstart` and `oddstart`) based on the total length of the `message` entered by the user. `evenstart = 0;` and `oddstart = (msglen + 1) / 2;`

Then just loop over the characters in the message entered by the user writing even characters at `encrypt[evenstart++]` and odd characters at `encrypt[oddstart++]`. (don't forget to *nul-terminate* `encrypt` if you will be using it as a string for output purposes.

Putting it together you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (void) {

    char message[MAXC],
        encrypt[MAXC];
    size_t len, evenstart = 0, oddstart;

    fputs ("enter message: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (message, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* validate message entered */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return 1;
    }

    message[(len = strcspn(message, "\r\n"))] = 0;  /* trim '\n', get len */
    oddstart = (len + 1) / 2;       /* get oddstart (add 1 before divide) */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)        /* loop over each char */
        if (i & 1)      /* if odd, write char at oddstart */
            encrypt[oddstart++] = message[i];
        else            /* if even, write at evenstart */
            encrypt[evenstart++] = message[i];
    encrypt[len] = 0;   /* nul-terminate */

    printf ("message : '%s'\nencrypt : '%s'\n", message, encrypt);
}
```

(**note:** you can use `i % 2` to check even/odd if you like, or simply `i & 1` -- in binary, if the ones-bit is `1` it's odd, otherwise its even -- up to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/encrevenodd
enter message: tes
message : 'tes'
encrypt : 'tse'

$ ./bin/encrevenodd
enter message: test
message : 'test'
encrypt : 'tset'

$ ./bin/encrevenodd
enter message: tests
message : 'tests'
encrypt : 'tsset'

$ ./bin/encrevenodd
enter message: my dog has fleas
message : 'my dog has fleas'
encrypt : 'm o a laydghsfes'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are terminated by the null byte ('\0' or ascii value 0) just so it knows where the string ends. Since the even and odd character arrays were not terminated by the null byte, strcat does not know when to stop appending characters. So the garbage values you see is because strcat keeps appending characters until you luckily find a 0 in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C do not know their length, they're just pointers. Strings must be terminated with a null character in order for functions like `printf` and `strlen` to know when to stop.

```
char even[SIZE];
char odd[SIZE];
```

At this point `even` and `odd` both contain whatever garbage was in memory at that time.

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i+=2){
    even[i/2]=message[i];
}

for(int i=1;i<length;i+=2){
    odd[j]=message[i];
    j++;
}
```

Now the beginning of `odd` and `even` have been filled in, but they were not null terminated.

```
printf("The even letters are: %s\n",even);
printf("The odd letters are: %s\n",odd);
```

These will start at where `even` and `odd` point, print the characters you've put in there, and then keep on printing whatever garbage was in memory until they happen to hit a null character.

---

The fix is to either zero out the memory with `memset`.

```
memset(even, '\0', SIZE);
memset(odd, '\0', SIZE);
```

Or ensure that `even` and `odd` are null terminated once you're done with them.

```
for(i=0;i<length;i+=2){
    even[i/2]=message[i];
}
even[i/2] = '\0';

for(i=1;i<length;i+=2){
    odd[j]=message[i];
    j++;
}
odd[j] = '\0';
```

---

Side note, `even` and `odd` loops can be done with the same technique.

```
for( i=0,j=0; i<length; i+=2,j++ ) {
    even[j]=message[i];
}
even[j] = '\0';

for( i=1,j=0; i<length; i+=2,j++ ) {
    odd[j]=message[i];
}
odd[j] = '\0';
```

Then we can observe that the only difference is where we start reading `message`. That means we can put this in a function and always remember to null terminate the result.

```
void copy_every_other_character(const char *src, char *dst) {
    int i,j,length = 0;
    length = strlen(src);
    for( i=0,j=0; i<length; i+=2,j++ ) {
        dst[j] = src[i];
    }
    dst[j] = '\0';
}

copy_every_other_character(message, even);
copy_every_other_character(message+1, odd);
```

Adding 1 to `message` means `copy_every_other_character` will get a pointer to the second character of `message` and go on from there. If `message` is `01234` it will see `1234`.

Comment: Aside, "Strings in C do not know their length, they're just pointers." promotes the view _strings_ as pointers, wheres   _strings_ are more like _arrays_ as in 'A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.".

Comment: @chux I think that's too subtle for this level of understanding. I'm not even sure what you're getting at. The important thing is the whatever-you-want-to-calll-it has to be null terminated.